# Pdfs on my iPad to my pc

Tags: itunes, ipad, pdf

I have downloaded some pdf files I need them for school but would like to read them on my PC at home. how do I get them to my PC.

Answer (score 2):

Email might be the most noob-friendly.

Comment: lol True enough Randy.

Comment: As @Mr Andyface mentions a few answers below, doing this thru iTunes and iBooks is a good alternative. Plus it gives you the extra benefit that you are keeping a backup of your PDF's in your iTunes library.

Answer (score 2):

If you have opened the pdf in ibooks on your iPad then when you sync the iPad they should appear in the books section in iTunes. You may need to turn this section on. From the menu bar click iTunes > Preferences (on a mac) Edit > Preferences - then in the General tab tick the box next to books.

It doesn't separate them out into ebooks and pdfs like iBooks does, but if you know what it's called you should be able to find it easy enough.

If you need to find in on your hard drive then right click the file and click 'show in finder' (on a mac) - not sure what you'd click on a PC.

hope that help

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com). It has [an iOS app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropbox/id327630330?mt=8) that you can use with your iPad and a PC app as well. Just drop files into the dropbox folder and it will be synced to both your iPad and PC.

Comment: While I do think Dropbox is great, I don't think this solves the issue. The problem is that the pdf is downloaded to the iPad, and OP wants to move it to PC. Currently Dropbox on iPhone/iPad doesn't enable the "Open in" functionality, to allow moving the pdf from iBooks/email to Dropbox. I wish it did, however.

Comment: Dropbox on iOS devices does support "Open in", its the icon on the top-right. (I just verified with my iPad to be sure.)